# Broken Admin Console After Modifying Pentaho Demo Databases to MySQL

Tags: mysql, console, admin, config, pentaho

I was following the tutorial on how to configure Pentaho to use mysql databases in:
http://interestingittips.wordpress.com/2011/05/05/complete-pentaho-installation-on-ubuntu-part-2/#comment-191

The author said that, ” You should see a connection error as it tries to connect with the Pentaho Server. But close it, for adding datasources its ok.” in step 9. I was however hoping for a way to correct the error. I tried:

1. Stopping all services and restarting the admin console
2. Updating my web.xml in tomcat\webapps to reflect my ip address

   TrustedIpAddrs
   127.0.0.1,192.168.223.35
3. Clearing my web history
   None of the above seemed to work. I don’t know if you have a better solution. Your assistance will be greatly appreciated.
   This is the error I am getting:
   Error
   Connection refused. This is the log from server.log:
   The pentaho forum post has the full server.log file:
   http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?90785-Broken-Admin-Console-After-Modifying-Pentaho-Demo-Databases-to-MySQL&p=274899#post274899

   ```
   2012-02-28 10:03:23,603 INFO  [org.pentaho.pac.server.JettyServer] Console is now started. It can be accessed using http://rumbi-desktop:8099 or http://127.0.1.1:8099
   2012-02-28 10:04:27,578 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version] Hibernate Annotations 3.3.1.GA
   2012-02-28 10:04:27,796 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] Hibernate 3.2.6
   2012-02-28 10:04:27,845 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] hibernate.properties not found
   2012-02-28 10:04:27,891 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] Bytecode provider name : cglib
   2012-02-28 10:04:27,952 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
   2012-02-28 10:04:28,596 INFO  [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector] I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused
   2012-02-28 10:04:28,596 INFO  [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector] Retrying request
   2012-02-28 10:04:28,607 INFO  [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector] I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused
   2012-02-28 10:04:28,607 INFO  [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector] Retrying request
   2012-02-28 10:04:28,608 INFO  [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector] I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused
   2012-02-28 10:04:28,608 INFO  [org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector] Retrying request
   2012-02-28 10:04:28,923 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] configuring from file: mysql5.hibernate.cfg.xml
   2012-02-28 10:04:28,944 DEBUG [org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver] trying to resolve system-id [http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd]
   2012-02-28 10:04:28,944 DEBUG [org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver] recognized hibernate namespace; attempting to resolve on classpath under org/hibernate/
   2012-02-28 10:04:28,945 DEBUG [org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver] located [http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd] in classpath
   2012-02-28 10:04:28,995 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider
   2012-02-28 10:04:28,995 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] hibernate.generate_statistics=true
   2012-02-28 10:04:28,995 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
   2012-02-28 10:04:28,995 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   2012-02-28 10:04:28,996 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate
   2012-02-28 10:04:28,996 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
   2012-02-28 10:04:28,996 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] connection.username=hibuser
   2012-02-28 10:04:28,996 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] connection.password=password
   2012-02-28 10:04:28,996 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] connection.pool_size=10
   2012-02-28 10:04:28,997 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] show_sql=false
   2012-02-28 10:04:28,997 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary=true
   2012-02-28 10:04:28,997 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
   2012-02-28 10:04:28,997 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration] null<-org.dom4j.tree.DefaultAttribute@8dba6b [Attribute: name resource value "hibernate/mysql5innodb.hbm.xml"]
   2012-02-28 10:04:28,997 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] Reading mappings from resource : hibernate/mysql5innodb.hbm.xml
   2012-02-28 10:04:29,543 DEBUG [org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver] trying to resolve system-id [http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd]
   2012-02-28 10:04:29,546 DEBUG [org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver] recognized hibernate namespace; attempting to resolve on classpath under org/hibernate/
   2012-02-28 10:04:29,547 DEBUG [org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver] located [http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd] in classpath
   2012-02-28 10:04:29,694 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration] null<-org.dom4j.tree.DefaultAttribute@17ef051 [Attribute: name resource value "PentahoUser.hbm.xml"]
   2012-02-28 10:04:29,694 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] Reading mappings from resource : PentahoUser.hbm.xml
   2012-02-28 10:04:29,711 DEBUG [org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver] trying to resolve system-id [http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd]
   2012-02-28 10:04:29,711 DEBUG [org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver] recognized hibernate namespace; attempting to resolve on classpath under org/hibernate/
   2012-02-28 10:04:29,712 DEBUG [org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver] located [http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd] in classpath
   2012-02-28 10:04:29,784 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration] null<-org.dom4j.tree.DefaultAttribute@1b08ca4 [Attribute: name resource value "PentahoRole.hbm.xml"]
   2012-02-28 10:04:29,784 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] Reading mappings from resource : PentahoRole.hbm.xml
   2012-02-28 10:04:29,786 DEBUG [org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver] trying to resolve system-id [http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd]
   2012-02-28 10:04:29,795 DEBUG [org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver] recognized hibernate namespace; attempting to resolve on classpath under org/hibernate/
   2012-02-28 10:04:29,795 DEBUG [org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver] located [http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd] in classpath
   2012-02-28 10:04:29,842 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] Configured SessionFactory: null
   2012-02-28 10:04:29,842 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] properties:       {show_sql=false, java.vendor=Oracle Corporation, sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD,      hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate,     sun.management.compiler=HotSpot Client Compiler, os.name=Linux,   sun.boot.class.path=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_02/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_02 /jre/lib/rt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_02/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_02/jr e/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_02/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_02/jre/lib/ch arsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_02/jre/classes, CONSOLE_HOME=., sun.desktop=gnome, java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, hibernate.generate_statistics=true, java.runtime.version=1.7.0_02-b13, hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider, user.name=root, log4j.configuration=resource/config/log4j.xml, connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, user.language=en, sun.boot.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_02/jre/lib/i386, dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect, java.version=1.7.0_02, user.timezone=Africa/Johannesburg, sun.arch.data.model=32, java.endorsed.dirs=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_02/jre/lib/endorsed, sun.cpu.isalist=, sun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8, file.encoding.pkg=sun.io, file.separator=/, java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification, java.class.version=51.0, user.country=ZA, connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate, java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_02/jre, java.vm.info=mixed mode, os.version=2.6.32-21-generic, path.separator=:, connection.password=password, java.vm.version=22.0-b10, hibernate.connection.password=password, java.awt.printerjob=sun.print.PSPrinterJob, sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle, awt.toolkit=sun.awt.X11.XToolkit, hibernate.connection.username=hibuser, user.home=/root, java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update, java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib, java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/, hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, connection.username=hibuser, java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation, hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect, hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary=true, java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment, sun.java.command=org.pentaho.pac.server.JettyServer, java.class.path=.:resource/config::./jdbc/hsqldb-1.8.0.7.jar:./jdbc/mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar:./lib/antlr-2.7.6.jar:./lib/asm-1.5.3.jar:./lib/asm-2.2.3.jar:./lib/asm-attrs-1.5.3.jar:./lib/asm-attrs-2.2.3.jar:./lib/avalon-framework-4.1.3.jar:./lib/cglib-2.1_3.jar:./lib/commons-beanutils-1.6.jar:./lib/commons-codec-1.3.jar:./lib/commons-collections-3.2.jar:./lib/commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar:./lib/commons-io-1.4.jar:./lib/commons-lang-2.2.jar:./lib/commons-logging-1.1.jar:./lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:./lib/ehcache-core-2.0.1.jar:./lib/ejb3-persistence-1.0.1.GA.jar:./lib/groovy-all-1.5.6.jar:./lib/gwt-datepicker-r30.jar:./lib/gwt-dnd-3.0.1.jar:./lib/gwt-incubator- 2.0.1.jar:./lib/gwt-servlet-2.0.3.jar:./lib/gwt-widgets-0.2.0.jar:./lib/hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar:./lib/hibernate-annotations-3.3.1.GA.jar:./lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-3.0.0.ga.jar:./lib/javassist-3.4.ga.jar:./lib/jaxen-1.1.jar:./lib/jetty-6.1.2.jar:./lib/jetty-gwt-6.1.9.jar:./lib/jetty-plus-6.1.2.jar:./lib/jetty-util-6.1.9.jar:./lib/jta-1.0.1B.jar:./lib/log4j-1.2.12.jar:./lib/log4j-1.2.14.jar:./lib/logkit-1.0.1.jar:./lib/pentaho-actionsequence-dom-2.3.4.jar:./lib/pentaho-bi-platform-api-3.10.0-stable.jar:./lib/pentaho-bi-platform-engine-core-3.10.0-stable.jar:./lib/pentaho-bi-platform-engine-security-3.10.0-stable.jar:./lib/pentaho-bi-platform-engine-services-3.10.0-stable.jar:./lib/pentaho-bi-platform-repository-3.10.0-stable.jar:./lib/pentaho-bi-platform-security-userroledao-3.10.0-stable.jar:./lib/pentaho-bi-platform-util-3.10.0-stable.jar:./lib/pentaho-connections-2.2.3.jar:./lib/pentaho-gwt-widgets-3.1.2.jar:./lib/pentaho-gwt-widgets-3.1.2-sources.jar:./lib/pentaho-open-admin-console-3.10.0-stable.jar:./lib/pentaho-open-admin-console-3.10.0-stable-sources.jar:./lib/pentaho-open-admin-console-messages-3.10.0-stable.jar:./lib/pentaho-xul-core-3.3.2.jar:./lib/servlet-api-2.3.jar:./lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:./lib/slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar:./lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar:./lib/spring-2.5.6.jar:./lib/spring-security-core-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:./lib/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification, java.vm.specification.version=1.7, sun.cpu.endian=little, sun.os.patch.level=unknown, hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true, connection.pool_size=10, java.io.tmpdir=/tmp, java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/, os.arch=i386, java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment, java.ext.dirs=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_02/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext, user.dir=/opt/Pentaho/administration-console, line.separator=
   ```

   , java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, java.security.auth.login.config=resource/config/login.conf, cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider, file.encoding=UTF-8, java.specification.version=1.7, jetty.home=., hibernate.show_sql=false, hibernate.connection.pool_size=10}
       2012-02-28 10:04:29,920 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration] Validator not present in classpath, ignoring event listener registration
       2012-02-28 10:04:29,936 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.search.SearchConfiguration] Search not present in classpath, ignoring event listener registration
       2012-02-28 10:04:29,936 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] Preparing to build session factory with filters : {}
       2012-02-28 10:04:29,936 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration] Execute first pass mapping processing
       2012-02-28 10:04:30,282 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration] Process hbm files
       2012-02-28 10:04:30,439 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapping class: org.pentaho.platform.repository.runtime.RuntimeElement -> RTELEMENT
       2012-02-28 10:04:30,512 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: instanceId -> INSTANCEID
      2012-02-28 10:04:30,514 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: revision -> REVISION
      2012-02-28 10:04:30,608 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: parentId -> PARID
      2012-02-28 10:04:30,608 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: parentType -> PARTYPE
      2012-02-28 10:04:30,608 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: solutionId -> SOLNID
      2012-02-28 10:04:30,641 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapping collection: org.pentaho.platform.repository.runtime.RuntimeElement.paramMapSS -> SSPARAMS
      2012-02-28 10:04:30,697 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: paramMapSS
      2012-02-28 10:04:30,698 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapping collection: org.pentaho.platform.repository.runtime.RuntimeElement.typesMap -> PARAMTYPESMAP
      2012-02-28 10:04:30,700 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: typesMap
      2012-02-28 10:04:30,707 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapping collection: org.pentaho.platform.repository.runtime.RuntimeElement.paramMapLS -> LSPARAMS
      2012-02-28 10:04:30,708 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: paramMapLS
      2012-02-28 10:04:30,708 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapping collection: org.pentaho.platform.repository.runtime.RuntimeElement.paramMapDT -> DTPARAMS
       2012-02-28 10:04:30,708 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: paramMapDT
      2012-02-28 10:04:30,708 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapping collection: org.pentaho.platform.repository.runtime.RuntimeElement.paramMapBD -> BDPARAMS
       2012-02-28 10:04:30,708 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: paramMapBD
       2012-02-28 10:04:30,708 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapping collection: org.pentaho.platform.repository.runtime.RuntimeElement.paramMapLong -> LNGPARAMS
       2012-02-28 10:04:30,709 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: paramMapLong
       2012-02-28 10:04:30,709 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapping collection: org.pentaho.platform.repository.runtime.RuntimeElement.paramMapCPLX -> CPLXPARAMS
       2012-02-28 10:04:30,709 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: paramMapCPLX
       2012-02-28 10:04:30,709 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: readOnly -> READONLY
       2012-02-28 10:04:30,709 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: createDate -> CREATED
       2012-02-28 10:04:30,710 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapping class: org.pentaho.platform.repository.content.ContentLocation -> CONTENTLOCATION
       2012-02-28 10:04:30,710 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: id -> CONTENTID
       2012-02-28 10:04:30,723 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: revision -> REVISION
       2012-02-28 10:04:30,723 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: name -> NAME
       2012-02-28 10:04:30,723 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: solutionId -> SOLNID
       2012-02-28 10:04:30,723 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: description -> DESCRIPTION
       2012-02-28 10:04:30,739 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: dirPath -> DIRPATH
       2012-02-28 10:04:30,739 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Named query: org.pentaho.platform.repository.content.ContentLocation.findContentLocationByPath ->

   from org.pentaho.platform.repository.content.ContentLocation cLoc where cLoc.dirPath = :inPath
       2012-02-28 10:04:30,755 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Named query: org.pentaho.platform.repository.content.ContentLocation.findAllContentLocations ->

   from org.pentaho.platform.repository.content.ContentLocation cLoc

   ```
   2012-02-28 10:04:30,755 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Named query: org.pentaho.platform.repository.content.ContentLocation.locationSearcher ->
   ```

   from org.pentaho.platform.repository.content.ContentLocation loc where 
      name like :searchTerm or description like :searchTerm or dirPath like :searchTerm

   ```
   2012-02-28 10:04:30,759 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapping class: org.pentaho.platform.repository.content.ContentItem -> CONTENTITEM
   2012-02-28 10:04:30,759 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: id -> CONTITEMID
   2012-02-28 10:04:30,764 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: revision -> REVISION
   2012-02-28 10:04:30,764 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: name -> NAME
   2012-02-28 10:04:31,410 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: parent -> parent_id
   2012-02-28 10:04:31,410 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: path -> PATH
   2012-02-28 10:04:31,410 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: title -> TITLE
   2012-02-28 10:04:31,418 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: mimeType -> MIMETYPE
   2012-02-28 10:04:31,419 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: url -> URL
   2012-02-28 10:04:31,419 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: latestVersionNum -> LATESTVERNUM
   2012-02-28 10:04:31,419 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: extension -> EXTENSION
   2012-02-28 10:04:31,419 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: writeMode -> WRITEMODE
   2012-02-28 10:04:31,419 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Named query: org.pentaho.platform.repository.content.ContentItem.findItemByPath ->
   ```

   from org.pentaho.platform.repository.content.ContentItem cItem where cItem.path = :inPath

   ```
   2012-02-28 10:04:31,419 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Named query: org.pentaho.platform.repository.content.ContentItem.findItemByName ->
   ```

   from org.pentaho.platform.repository.content.ContentItem cItem where cItem.parent = :parent and cItem.name = :name

   ```
   2012-02-28 10:04:31,419 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Named query: org.pentaho.platform.repository.content.ContentItem.itemSearcher ->
   ```

   from org.pentaho.platform.repository.content.ContentItem itm where 
      name like :searchTerm or title like :searchTerm or path like :searchTerm

   ```
   2012-02-28 10:04:31,420 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapping class: org.pentaho.platform.repository.content.ContentItemFile -> CONTITEMFILE
   2012-02-28 10:04:31,420 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: id -> CONTIFILEID
   2012-02-28 10:04:31,420 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: revision -> REVISION
   2012-02-28 10:04:31,420 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: osFileName -> OSFILENAME
   2012-02-28 10:04:31,420 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: osPath -> OSPATH
   2012-02-28 10:04:31,421 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: actionName -> ACTNAME
   2012-02-28 10:04:31,421 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: parent -> parent_id
   2012-02-28 10:04:31,421 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: fileSize -> FILESIZE
   2012-02-28 10:04:31,421 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: fileDateTime -> FILEDATETIME
   2012-02-28 10:04:31,421 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: initialized -> ISINITIALIZED
   2012-02-28 10:04:31,421 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Named query: org.pentaho.platform.repository.content.ContentItemFile.agingContentSearcher ->
   ```

   from org.pentaho.platform.repository.content.ContentItemFile itmFile where 
      fileDateTime < :archiveDate

   ```
   2012-02-28 10:04:31,422 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapping class:  org.pentaho.platform.repository.content.BackgroundExecutedContentId -> BGCONTENTID
   2012-02-28 10:04:31,422 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: id -> BGCONTID
   2012-02-28 10:04:31,422 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: revision -> REVISION
   2012-02-28 10:04:31,431 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: userName -> BGUSER
   2012-02-28 10:04:31,431 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Named query: org.pentaho.platform.repository.content.BackgroundExecutedContentId.findIdsByUser -> 
       from
       org.pentaho.platform.repository.content.BackgroundExecutedContentId
       bgItem where bgItem.userName = :user

   2012-02-28 10:04:31,431 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Named query:  org.pentaho.platform.repository.content.BackgroundExecutedContentId.findAllIds -> 
       select cItem from
       org.pentaho.platform.repository.content.ContentItem cItem,
       org.pentaho.platform.repository.content.BackgroundExecutedContentId
       bgId where cItem.id = bgId.id

   2012-02-28 10:04:31,431 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Named query: org.pentaho.platform.repository.content.BackgroundExecutedContentId.findBackgroundContentItemsForUsers -> 
       select cItem from
       org.pentaho.platform.repository.content.ContentItem cItem,
       org.pentaho.platform.repository.content.BackgroundExecutedContentId
       bgId where cItem.id = bgId.id and bgId.userName = :user

   2012-02-28 10:04:31,431 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapping class: org.pentaho.platform.repository.subscription.Schedule -> PRO_SCHEDULE
   2012-02-28 10:04:31,443 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: id -> SCHEDULEID
   2012-02-28 10:04:31,444 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: revision -> REVISION
   2012-02-28 10:04:31,444 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: title -> SCHEDTITLE
   2012-02-28 10:04:31,444 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: scheduleReference -> SCHEDREF
   2012-02-28 10:04:31,445 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: description -> SCHEDDESC
   2012-02-28 10:04:31,445 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder] Mapped property: cronString -> CRONSTRING
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to specify the path to your solution repository in the web.xml?

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>solution-path</param-name>
    <param-value>/path/to/biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions</param-value>
</context-param>
```